# MVC 6 UseOAuthBearerAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-core-mvc, bearer-token

In MVC 6 RCP 6 using Microsoft.AspNet.Security I was able to use a custom SecurityTokenValidator.

In RC Microsoft.AspNet.Security didn't exist in Beta4 so I changed my code to use Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication see below: (Compiles and runs but SecurityTokenValidator never fires.

```
services.Configure<ExternalAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = OAuthBearerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(options =>
{           
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RequireSignedTokens = false;
    options.AuthenticationScheme = OAuthBearerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
    options.SecurityTokenValidators = new List<ISecurityTokenValidator> { validator };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication code with

```
app.UseMiddleware<OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware>(new ConfigureOptions<OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
                options.SecurityTokenValidators = new List<ISecurityTokenValidator> { validator };
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it?

Today occours that CustomSecurityValidationToken not fires because inner exception was throw (a inner validation occurs based in params in my case).
Try to debug Notifications and if it fires 'AuthenticationFailed', you will find in 'context' variable a Property named 'Exception' if any.

```
  app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(bearer =>
        {                
            bearer.SecurityTokenValidators = new List<ISecurityTokenValidator>() { new CustomSecurityValidationToken() };
            bearer.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
            bearer.Notifications = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                SecurityTokenReceived = context =>
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                MessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });
```